# JMeter Selenium Web Driver Integration Issue

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, jmeter, webdriver

I am using JMeter Version 5.4.1

Chrome Browser Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I setup Chrome Driver Config in JMeter and added the path to my downloaded ChromeDriver exe in my C Folder: C:\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe

I added JMeter Sampler (WebDriver Sampler)
The Script language is Java
Added below Script:

```
*WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get('https://google.com');
var searchBox = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.name("q"));
searchBox.sendKeys("Automation");
searchBox.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();*
```

When I run in JMeter, I get the error below:
*

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); WDS.browser.get('https://google.com'); var searc . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 19.  Encountered: "t" (116), after : "\'h": <at unknown location>
 in <unknown file>
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:93)
at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46)
at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:86)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831
```

- 

Comment: Use double quotes `("https://google.com")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using the same version of chrome browser. and I'm using your code, it works fine didn't face any issues. Your chrome driver may be the cause of that issue or Jmeter version. PFA

[Jmeter Webdriver Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UTJr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no "Java" language available for scripting in the WebDriver sampler, what is called "Java" is [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter so I would recommend reconsidering the language choice because:

   - Beanshell doesn't support modern Java features like [Generics, diamond operators,](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/issues/66) etc.
   - [It's recommended to use Groovy language since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
   - Groovy has better compatibility with Java code than Beanshell moreover [it adds some syntax sugar on top](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
2. Your code won't compile either in Java or Beanshell because single quotation marks are reserved for Char and you're using String. So change this line:

   ```
   WDS.browser.get('https://google.com');
   ```

   to this

   ```
   WDS.browser.get("https://google.com");
   ```

   and the code will start working normally (however it will work without any changes in Groovy)